# Access cookie from http-cookie-agent in typescript

Tags: typescript, axios, httpcookie, cookiejar

I am trying to access a cookie from axios. I am unable to use the wrapper but can use `http-cookie-agent` directly.

I can set the cookie, but I am unable to retrieve it again.

The cookie is set like this:

```
export function setupAxios(
  basePath: string,
  config?: { initialCookie?: string | Cookie }
) {
  const jar = new CookieJar();
  if (config) {
    const { initialCookie } = config;
    if (typeof initialCookie !== "undefined") {
      jar.setCookieSync(initialCookie, basePath);
    }
  }
  const httpsCookieAgent = new HttpsCookieAgent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    cookies: { jar },
  });
  const axios = Axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    timeout: 1000,
    httpsAgent: httpsCookieAgent,
  });

  return axios;
}
```

which is called like this: `export const axios = setupAxios(basePath);`

I have a function `clearCookies` in which I get the agent:

```
export function clearCookies() {
  const httpsAgent = axios.defaults.httpsAgent as typeof HttpsCookieAgent;
  console.log(httpsAgent);
  >>> const options = httpsAgent.[Symbol(cookieOptions)] as CookieAgentOptions; <<< This I don't know how to accomplish.
  const jar = options.cookies?.jar;
  jar?.removeAllCookiesSync();
}
```

I can log out the dictionary:

```
CookieAgent {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    free: [Function (anonymous)],
    newListener: [Function: maybeEnableKeylog]
  },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  defaultPort: 443,
  protocol: 'https:',
  options: [Object: null prototype] { rejectUnauthorized: false, path: null },
  requests: [Object: null prototype] {},
  sockets: [Object: null prototype] {
    'example.com:443::::::::false:::::::::::::': [ [TLSSocket] ]
  },
  freeSockets: [Object: null prototype] {},
  keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
  keepAlive: false,
  maxSockets: Infinity,
  maxFreeSockets: 256,
  scheduling: 'lifo',
  maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
  totalSocketCount: 1,
  maxCachedSessions: 100,
  _sessionCache: {
    map: {
      'example.com:443::::::::false:::::::::::::': <Buffer 30 82 03 1f 02 01 01 02 02 03 04 04 02 13 02 04 20 aa 87 c2 15 2c 23 f2 11 6e f0 fe ce d5 b1 a3 b4 dd 53 01 08 76 ce c0 5e 7e 18 fe cd 11 2d 7c 89 04 ... 753 more bytes>
    },
    list: [ 'example.com:443::::::::false:::::::::::::' ]
  },
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(cookieOptions)]: {
    jar: CookieJar {
      rejectPublicSuffixes: true,
      enableLooseMode: false,
      allowSpecialUseDomain: false,
      store: { idx: {
        'example.com': {
          '/': {
            id0: Cookie="id0=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpIjoiMTI3ZTA4NjYtNmJjZi00ZDAxLThjZTItNDRkNDg1OTI4MTRjIiwibCI6IjIwZDIxMzg4LWNjNzctNGM4Ni04N2JkLTRiNjE1NzU5OGEwYSJ9.SvP-cnS8docWhAGPKHm8YOjICmYp8BjWFFr-gv75WJE; Expires=Mon, 20 Jun 2022 19:00:59 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; hostOnly=true; aAge=9ms; cAge=352ms"
          }
        }
      } },
      prefixSecurity: 'silent',
      _cloneSync: [Function (anonymous)],
      _importCookiesSync: [Function (anonymous)],
      getCookiesSync: [Function (anonymous)],
      getCookieStringSync: [Function (anonymous)],
      getSetCookieStringsSync: [Function (anonymous)],
      removeAllCookiesSync: [Function (anonymous)],
      setCookieSync: [Function (anonymous)],
      serializeSync: [Function (anonymous)]
    }
  }
}
```

The cookie is clearly there, I am however unable to retrieve it. I have imported

`import { HttpsCookieAgent, CookieAgentOptions, CookieOptions } from "http-cookie-agent/http";`

and if I'd be able to set the `CookieAgentOptions` I could access the cookie (at least according to `vscode`). But I don't know how to write code that accesses
`[Symbol(cookieOptions)]`

`httpsAgent.defaultPort` works fine and gets me 443, but how do I handle the symbol?

Comment: Could you possibly iterate over the key if its enumerable and then get the value like that?

Comment: That's a nice idea, but unfortunately nothing is put out when looping. Tried several approaches, none worked.

Comment: Another thing you could try, is that if the key is created using `Symbol.for("cookieOptions")`, you could access the options with `httpsAgent[Symbol.for("cookieOptions")]`.

Comment: @catgirlkelly  That didn't work either, but the idea to loop put me on the right track. You have to use the `Object.getOwnerPropertySymbols` method to get an iterator over the symbols. From there, you can pull the right symbol by comparing its string version. I'll answer it to show how it is done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea to loop brought me on the right track.
I also had to remove the typecasting. Now you can access the cookie
e.g. this way:

```
export function clearCookies() {
  const httpsAgent = axios.defaults.httpsAgent;
  for (let sym of Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(httpsAgent)) {
    if (sym.toString() === "Symbol(cookieOptions)") {
      const jar = httpsAgent[sym].jar as CookieJar;
      jar.removeAllCookiesSync();
    }
  }
}
```

Still, I'd prefer some way of accessing the symbol directly.